# How to add each elements of two unequal arrays and store it in third array?

Tags: c

I want a code that adds each elements of arr1 to each element of arr2 and store it in a third array. For example if `arr1={1,2,3}` and `arr2={1,2}` then `arr3={2,3,3,4,4,5}` would be something like this.

Please help.Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an assignment or interview question. Please share what have you tried and where you are facing the issue?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question is a bit unclear. What exactly is it that you're asking for help with? On my end I don't understand how arr1 and arr2 combine to make arr3, there doesn't seem to be any pattern to it, however, is *that* your question? Is it how to create an array that is your question? Please clarify what your question really is.

Comment: Okay, then you have to write it, this isn't a free coding service. Ask here when you run into specific problems.

Comment: I know how to add each elements of two array. I am having trouble storing it in a third array whose length would be equal to product of element of first and second array.

Comment: LasseVågsætherKarlsen it seems to be each element of array 1 added to each element of array 2, separately pushed into array 3

Comment: Yup buffy that's my question. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite your bad explanation, i think this is what you are looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
    int b[] = {1, 2};

    int numElementsA = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int);
    int numElementsB = sizeof(b) / sizeof(int);

    int finalSize = numElementsA * numElementsB;
    printf("finalSize: %i\n", finalSize);

    int* c = malloc(finalSize * sizeof(int));
    int cc = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < numElementsA; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < numElementsB; y++) {
            c[cc] = a[x] + b[y];
            cc++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < finalSize; i++) {
        printf("%i ,", c[i]);
    }

    //make sure memory doesn't leak
    free(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
finalSize: 6
2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5,
```

Comment: Won't x+y give a result twice in execution of the loop? for example when x=0 and y=1 x+y=1 and when x=1 and y=0 x+y=1. Won't it overwrite the memory in c[x+y]?

Comment: malloc(finalSize * sizeof(int));

Comment: whoops, you are correct. i fixed it :) it's been ages since i've done C unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to c so i didn't knew about malloc function. Will study about it :)

Answer (score -2):

Allocate result array with the length: input array1 size * input array2, then do the calculations.

Comment: i know the length of the result array. how to allocate it is my question.

Comment: use malloc or calloc